# Botão com borda a mais

Tags: css, button

Estou tendo um problema em um botão que criei do zero mas está mostrando uma borda que incomoda, não adicionei essa borda a mais nele, adicionei apenas uma borda normal em amarelo.
[Veja o botão](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmP7m.png)

Essa parte acizentada no lado direito e inferior. Meu código CSS está assim:

```
.btn-primary2 {
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 500;
color: #ffcf4a;
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 50px;
border-color:#ffcf4a;
padding: 7px 25px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-primary2:hover {
background-color: #ffcf4a;
color: white;
transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, podemos mudar como adicionamos a borda.

Ao invés de:

```
border-color:#ffcf4a;
```

Podemos definir o tipo de borda, a espessura e a cor, tudo na mesma linha. Pode ser isso que tenha bugado.

Tenta substituir essa linha do "border-color", por isso:

```
border: solid 2px #ffcf4a;
```

Funcionou aqui, acredito que funcione pra você também!